# Electron breakpad minidump version mismatch

Tags: linux, electron, minidump, google-breakpad

Trying to use minidump_stackwalk on crashdump generated from Electron application. But receiving the following error:

**ERROR: Minidump version mismatch: 0xbfef != 0xa793**

Any idea how to solve this problem?

From the same electron app, crash dumps are proper whereas others are not. Looked into Google Breakpad code, where the above version number `0xa793` is hardcoded inside

> /src/google_breakpad/common/minidump_format.h:#define MD_HEADER_VERSION   0x0000a793 /* 42899 */

Need to know from which breakpad source `0xbfef` was generated, so that corresponding code used to generate call stack.

Thanks in advance.